# Tracking 'objects' and labelling with the same labels between images/arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

This is essentially a question about blob/feature tracking in **MATLAB**.

I have a series of sequential arrays (for simplicity, say 5 at this stage) with a background of 0 values, and then multiple objects (blobs) within each array. This is in MATLAB. These blobs can change position and size, and appear or disappear altogether, between arrays.

I'd like to label any of the blobs that are in the same position between arrays with the same ID (either a number or a letter).

Also need to incorporate functionality so that if a new pixel is added to the edge of a blob in a previous image, then it would be given the same ID.

And some functionality so that if a blob appeared in any previous array (say it was in array 1, disappeared in arrays 2 and 3, and then reappeared in 4 and 5), then it would be given the same ID as it originally had in the 1st array.

I've currently been trying to use the bwlabel function in MATLAB to do this but obviously each sequential array is labelled independently of the previous ones, so there is no 'tracking' of blobs from one image to another, and the numbers for each blob change based on how many blobs there are in that array and their positions.

Would be very grateful of any thoughts/comments on how to do this. If further clarification is required on this question, please also let me know. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a good question, but out of the scope of SO. You can use `regionprops` to get the barycenters and then write some tracking algorithm, but this is a complicated processing, especially if your objects change shape/size.

Answer (score 0):

There is functionality for object tracking in the Computer Vision System Toolbox. There is an implementation of the Kalman filter (`vision.KalmanFilter`) that you can use to predict the location of an object in the next video frame, and a function called `assignDetectionsToTracks` that you can use to associate the objects across frames.  See the [Motion-Based Multiple Object Tracking](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html) example.